# Get row values by column name match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get the value of all the cells of rows. But not from all the rows, only rows having specific name in a specific column.

I attached a screenshot. I want to get all row values which "userID" is "user3". It means row 4 row 6 data.

[image: Screenshot of my data series]

I used following code.

```
    function getByName(colName, row) {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var col = data[0].indexOf(colName);
      if (col != -1) {
        return data[row-1][col];
      }
    }
```

Above I getting only specific cell value in the user ID column. Not all data in the ROW.

```
function getAllrowData() {
 
  var user3 = getByName("userID",2);
  var values = user3.getDisplayValues()
  Logger.log(values)
  return values
}
```

`getByname` giving only cell value.
I want following result so I can display data in html, belongs to only "user 3" in the image. Help me to correct my code.

```
C   25  30  0   16  user3  
E   28  36  6   19  user3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Data by Row Number and Column Name:

```
function getByName(user, colName = 'userID') {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const hA = data.shift();
  const idx = hA.reduce((a, h, i) => (a[h] = i, a), {});
  let o = data.map(r => {
    if (r[idx[colName]] == user) {
      return r;
    }
  }).filter(r => r );
  if (o && o.length > 0) {
    return o;
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't work for my problem.  it gives exact cell value. not all row data

Comment: Hello,  Here's an link to my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c5yWMxjbAj_qyJIApI86uF9BtDP8mUQ9CBzMicCGZig/edit?usp=sharing/)... Can you please clarify the reason"null" data?

Comment: Awesome. Got the answer. Your edited answer solved my question. Thank you. I don't have enough reputation to cast votes.

Comment: That's okay I don't really care about points

Comment: I tried to add headers to filtered values.  [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c5yWMxjbAj_qyJIApI86uF9BtDP8mUQ9CBzMicCGZig/edit?usp=sharing/)  My try isn't succeeded. Can you please suggest a short method to add headers to add headers to filtered data.

Comment: I don't really use filters in my own work

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[col]` from `return data[row-1][col];`

The above because `sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` return an Array of Arrays of values. Using two indexes returns a cell value, using only the first index will return an Array having all the row values.

Comment: But, issue is it gives data of Specified ROW NUMBER. I want only data "user3" mentioned in the "userID" column. Please suggest me modification. [ Actuallty, userID is an object in my app script)